# Compare structure of json objects javascript

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I'm writing a testing function postman, to check if json objects have the same keys and each key has the same datatype

I have 3 json objects

```
var test1 = {
    "abc" : 1,
    "qwe" : "random",
    "arrayExample" : [{"var1" : 11, "var2" : 22}, {"var1" : 21314, "var2" : 99}]
}


var test2 = {
    "abc" : 3,
    "qwe" : "Another String",
    "arrayExample" : [{"var1": 435, "var2": 897}]
}


var test3 = {
    "abc" : 46,
    "qwe" : "Nothing special",
    "arrayExample" : [{"var1": 098, "var9" : "string here"}]
}
```

I want to test that the keys, the value of each key are also of the same type.

For example, if my comparison function is called compare, which returns true if the objects are of the same type,

```
function compare(obj1, obj2){
    <NEED HELP HERE>
}
```

Then I need

```
compare(test1, test2) == true
```

and

```
compare(test1, test3) == compare(test2, test3) == false
```

because

```
typeOf( test1["arrayExample"] ) = typeOf( test2["arrayExample"] ) = array of same JSON type
```

BUT

```
typeOf( test3["arrayExample"]) = array of different json type
```

Comment: In JavaScript, there's no such thing as a char array or number array. So you'll need to first define what it means for two arrays to be "the same type" or not. What type would you consider `["a", 2]`? Is it the same type as `[1, "b"]`?

Comment: just create function(declare rules to check) and loop through your json objects:)

Comment: @smarx my arrays will contain JSONs and I'm going under the assumption that all will have the same json type in them. I'll just edit the question a little

Comment: @AgentWeirdo If I understand correctly, you'll just check the first element of the array, then, and either that matches or doesn't. Seems like you're about ready to start writing code! :-) Let us know if/when you have a specific question you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

If your question only dealt with comparing individual property values, you could do the following:

- Ensure both objects have the same number of keys.
- Ensure that the value types of same-named properties are the same.

```js
const tests = {
  4: {a: 1, b: "AA"},
  5: {b: "BB", a: 2},
  6: {a: 3, b: 999},
  7: {a: 4, c: "CC"},
  8: {a: 5, b: "DD", c: 999},
  9: {a: 6, b: "EE", c: undefined}
};

const compare = (obj1, obj2) => {
  let similar = true;
  const obj1Keys = Object.keys(obj1);
  const obj2Keys = Object.keys(obj2);
  if (obj1Keys.length !== obj2Keys.length) {
    similar = false;
  } else {
    obj1Keys.forEach(key => {
      similar = (typeof obj1[key] === typeof obj2[key]);
    });
  }
  return similar;
};

const check = (a, b) => {
  console.log(`Test objects ${a} and ${b} are similar? ${compare(tests[a], tests[b])}`);
};

check(4, 5);
check(4, 6);
check(4, 7);
check(4, 8);
check(4, 9);
```

For array properties, however, you can do a recursive check using the entire above procedure on all combinations of array elements in the arrays of same-named properties from both objects. e.g. if property "X" for object 1 has an array of 3 objects and property "X" for object 2 has an array of 4 objects (for a total of 7 objects), recursively use the above check to compare the first of those 7 objects against all 6 of the others, i.e. compare 1&2, 1&3, 1&4, 1&5, 1&6 and 1&7.

While I haven't tested it, and while your question didn't actually ask about this, this approach should actually even work for sub-nested arrays of objects, i.e. if an array contains objects which themselves contain arrays of objects, etc. This is because of the (potentially infinitely) recursive nature of the code.

```js
const tests = {
  1: {
    "abc" : 1,
    "qwe" : "random",
    "arrayExample" : [{"var1" : 11, "var2" : 22}, {"var1" : 21314, "var2" : 99}]
  },
  2: {
    "abc" : 3,
    "qwe" : "Another String",
    "arrayExample" : [{"var1": 435, "var2": 897}]
  },
  3: {
    "abc" : 46,
    "qwe" : "Nothing special",
    "arrayExample" : [{"var1": 098, "var9" : "string here"}]
  },
  
  11: {d: 11, e: [{f: 12, g: "FF"}, {f: 13, g: "GG"}                  ]},
  12: {d: 14, e: [{f: 15, g: "HH"}, {f: 16, g: "II"}, {f: 17, g: "JJ"}]},
  13: {d: 18, e: [{g: "KK", f: 19}                                    ]},
  14: {d: "", e: [{f: 20, g: "LL"}                                    ]},
  15: {d: 21, e: [{f: 22, g: 23  }                                    ]},
  16: {d: 24, e: [{f: 25, h: "MM"}                                    ]},
  17: {d: 26, e: [{f: 27, g: "MM", h: 28}                             ]},
};

const compare = (obj1, obj2) => {
  let similar = true;
  const obj1Keys = Object.keys(obj1);
  const obj2Keys = Object.keys(obj2);
  if (obj1Keys.length !== obj2Keys.length) {
    similar = false;
  } else {
    obj1Keys.forEach(key => {
      const val1 = obj1[key], val2 = obj2[key];
      if (Array.isArray(val1) === true) {
        if (Array.isArray(val2) === false) {
          similar = false;
        } else {
          const allSubObjs = [].concat(
            Object.keys(val1).map(subKey => val1[subKey]),
            Object.keys(val2).map(subKey => val2[subKey])
          );
          allSubObjs.splice(1).forEach(subObj => {
            const recursiveCheck = compare(allSubObjs[0], subObj);
            if (recursiveCheck === false) similar = false;
          });
        }
      } else if (typeof val1 !== typeof val2) similar = false;
    });
  }
  return similar;
};

const check = (a, b) => {
  console.log(`Test objects ${a} and ${b} are similar? ${compare(tests[a], tests[b])}`);
};

check(1, 2);
check(1, 3);
check(2, 3);

check(11, 12);
check(11, 13);
check(11, 14);
check(11, 15);
check(11, 16);
check(11, 17);
```